# Geting error as Did not find subcontext java: java.util.NoSuchElementException in wildfly 13 while connecting to a oracle 11 g Database

Tags: java, wildfly, jndi

I have migrated my JBOSS 5 built EJB and WEB project to wildlfy 13 and have used richfaces 4.5 and jsf 2.0 and successfully deployed. Project is all about fetching some logs from oracle 11g database. While connecting to the the Database I am getting error as: Did not find subcontext java:/folder(configured in db.jndi.properties) which in turn has to fetch values from a .xml file which has the Database details.

I have deployed the db.jndi.properties file and the .xml file into the deployment folder in the wildfly 13 server.

```
int i = 1;
    String name = dbJndi.getProperty(ENV + i);
    while (name != null)
    {
      String alias = dbJndi.getProperty(ALIAS + i, name);
      environments.add(new EnvironmentEntry(name, alias));
      i++;
      name = dbJndi.getProperty(ENV + i);
    }
    try
    {
      initialContext = new InitialContext();
      NamingEnumeration<Binding> bindingEnum;
      label321:
      for (Iterator localIterator = environments.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext(); bindingEnum.hasMoreElements())
      {
        EnvironmentEntry env = (EnvironmentEntry)localIterator.next();
        String jndiName = env.getJndiName();
        try
        {
          initialContext.lookup(jndiName);
        }
        catch (NameNotFoundException e)
        {
          System.out.println("Did not find subcontext " + jndiName);
          break label321;
```

INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) ********** Loaded application properties from file: /opt/wildfly/server/configuration/db.jndi.properties
INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Did not find subcontext java:folder
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.util.NoSuchElementException
ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)  at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862)

Comment: Please add the full stack trace and consider reading [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: 2019-09-12 18:03:38,270 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) ********** Loaded application properties from file: /opt/wildfly/server/configuration/db.jndi.properties
2019-09-12 18:03:38,271 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Did not find subcontext java:siam/z
2019-09-12 18:03:38,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.util.NoSuchElementException
2019-09-12 18:03:38,272 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862)
2019-09-12 18:03:38,273 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)         at com..web.Option.getLogEnvironments(Option.java:27)
2019-09-